# Pandas: Recommendation on how to handle missing decimal

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a scenario where the one of the record in the dataset contains empty value (simplified below for ease of understanding). there are two records in data, one with 0.1 and other with None. When I serialize `df1`, I get the response I want i.e null for second record.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import decimal


data = [{'A': 0.1}, {'A': None}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1.to_json(orient='records'))
```

prints `[{"A":0.1},{"A":null}]`

I want to treat A as decimal like below:

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df3['A'] = df2['A'].apply(lambda x: decimal.Decimal(x))
print(df3.to_json(orient='records')) # this throws exception
```

prints `OverflowError: Invalid Nan value when encoding double`

I would like to get the same result as `df1` i.e null for the missing  decimal in json. Note this works if I used float instead of decimal but that's not an option I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df3['A'] = df2['A'].apply(lambda x: (decimal.Decimal(x) if not pd.isnull(x) else None))
```